# pipes and tank question

Tags: word-problem

Three taps A, B and C can fill a tank in 12, 15 and 20 hours respectively. If A is open all the time and B and C are open for one hour each alternately, the tank will be full in:
A. 7 hours
B. 7.5 hours
C. 8 hours
D. 6 hours
The right solution of this is 7 hours but i get 7.05 I don't know what I'm doing wrong can someone help me just in the first steps?

Comment: Please show the calculation you carried out.

Comment: (1\12 + 1\15)x\2 + (1\12 + 1\20)x\2 =1  I tried this equation but it doesn't work I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: That equation appears to assume that it takes an even number of hours.  Hint:  Tap $B$ is on more often than tap $C$.

Comment: yeah but that doesn't really help

Comment: It should.  If you want to stick to your method, just remark that (at most) $B$ can be on for one more hour than $C$.  I'm not crazy about this method, as it seems to presume that the answer is an integer number of hours.  But it works here.

Comment: My method:  in alternate hours, we complete $\frac 1{12}+\frac 1{15}$ and $\frac 1{12}+\frac 1{20}$. So Just do a running sum until you get a total greater than or equal to $1$.  That will tell you which hour the work gets done in, at which point a formula like yours will work.

Comment: (1\12 + 1\15)(x+1) + (1\12 + 1\20)x=1 this gives x=3 and then the total time is x+(x+1) which is equal to 7

Comment: Right.  As I say, this works here because the answer is an integer.  It wouldn't work in general.

Comment: Solved or have any doubt?

Comment: yes i solved it

Answer (score 0):

Hint: When you let the taps on for 2 hours ($A$ for $2$, $B$ and $C$ for $1$), you fill in $2/12 + 1/15 + 1/20$ of the tank. Multiplying that number by $3$ gives $<1$ and multiplying that number by $4$ gives $>1$, so the answer can be neither $C$ or $D$. The one extra hour to $A$ fills in $1/12+1/15$ of the tank and the one-and-half extra hour to $B$ fills in $1/12\cdot3/2+1/15+1/20\cdot1/2$.